# Incorrect scaling in recursive IFFT implementation

Tags: c++, recursion, fft

I'm working on a simple recursive FFT/IFFT implementation in C++. The code is as follows:

```cpp
#include <complex>
#include <numbers>
#include <ranges>
#include <valarray>
#include <vector>

#include "assert.hpp"

template<typename T = float>
std::valarray<std::complex<T>> fft(std::valarray<std::complex<T>> const& data)
{
    const auto N = data.size();
    ASSERT(!(N & (N - 1)), "FFT length has to be power of two");

    if (N == 1)
        return data;

    auto even = fft(data[std::slice(0, N / 2, 2)]);
    auto odd = fft(data[std::slice(1, N / 2, 2)]);

    auto result = std::valarray<std::complex<T>>(N);
    for (size_t k = 0; k < N / 2; ++k)
    {
        auto t = std::exp(std::complex<T>(0, -2 * std::numbers::pi * T(k) / N));
        result[k] = even[k] + odd[k] * t;
        result[k + N / 2] = even[k] - odd[k] * t;
    }

    return result;
}

template<typename T = float>
std::valarray<std::complex<T>> ifft(std::valarray<std::complex<T>> const& data)
{
    const auto N = data.size();
    ASSERT(!(N & (N - 1)), "FFT length has to be a power of two");

    if (N == 1)
        return data;

    auto even = ifft(data[std::slice(0, N / 2, 2)]);
    auto odd = ifft(data[std::slice(1, N / 2, 2)]);

    auto result = std::valarray<std::complex<T>>(N);
    for (size_t k = 0; k < N / 2; ++k)
    {
        auto t = std::exp(std::complex<T>(0, 2 * std::numbers::pi * T(k) / N));
        result[k] = (even[k] + odd[k] * t) / T(N);
        result[k + N / 2] = (even[k] - odd[k] * t) / T(N);
    }

    return result;
}
```

While the forward FFT works fine, the inverse FFT scales it's output incorrectly (by 1/8 for FFTs of size 8).
I'm using this code to test my implementation:

```cpp
std::valarray<std::complex<float>> data = { 3, 5, 8, 9, 1, 4, 7, 2 };

std::cout << "Data: ";
for (auto const& e : data)
    std::cout << e << " ";
std::cout << "\n";

auto spectrum = fft(data);

std::cout << "Forward FFT: ";
for (auto const& e : spectrum)
    std::cout << e << " ";
std::cout << "\n";

std::cout << "Inverse FFT: ";
auto inverse = ifft(spectrum);
for (auto const& e : inverse)
    std::cout << e << " ";
std::cout << "\n";
```

Which yields this output:

```
Data: (3,0) (5,0) (8,0) (9,0) (1,0) (4,0) (7,0) (2,0) 
Forward FFT: (39,0) (-2.24264,-6.65685) (-11,2) (6.24264,-4.65685) (-1,0) (6.24264,4.65685) (-11,-2) (-2.24264,6.65685) 
Inverse FFT: (0.375,0) (0.625,6.58126e-09) (1,2.73196e-09) (1.125,-1.21692e-08) (0.125,0) (0.5,-1.20452e-08) (0.875,-2.73196e-09) (0.25,1.76331e-08)
```

According to numpy, the forward FFT is correct, while the inverse FFT should of course be the original data, which it isn't.

What causes this behaviour? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corrected IFFT function looks like this:

```cpp
template<typename T = float>
std::valarray<std::complex<T>> ifft(std::valarray<std::complex<T>> const& data)
{
    const auto M = data.size();
    ASSERT(!(M & (M - 1)), "FFT length has to be a power of two");

    auto ifft_ = [](std::valarray<std::complex<T>> const& data_, auto& ifft_) {
        const auto N = data_.size();

        if (N == 1)
            return data_;

        auto even = ifft_(data_[std::slice(0, N / 2, 2)], ifft_);
        auto odd = ifft_(data_[std::slice(1, N / 2, 2)], ifft_);

        auto result = std::valarray<std::complex<T>>(N);
        for (size_t k = 0; k < N / 2; ++k)
        {
            auto t =
                std::exp(std::complex<T>(0, 2 * std::numbers::pi * T(k) / N));
            result[k] = (even[k] + odd[k] * t);
            result[k + N / 2] = (even[k] - odd[k] * t);
        }

        return result;
    };

    return ifft_(data, ifft_) / T(M);
}
```

I was applying the scaling coefficient at every recursion step. The correct thing to do is to scale once after the entire IFFT is done.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: This is incorrect. Please see the accepted answer for a correct version. This answer is left for historical reference and for the comments.

I figured out what I was doing wrong: The scaling coefficient of `1/N` is incorrect. When using `1/sqrt(N)` it works perfectly.

The IFFT function has to be changed to this:

```cpp
template<typename T = float>
std::valarray<std::complex<T>> ifft(std::valarray<std::complex<T>> const& data)
{
    const auto N = data.size();
    ASSERT(!(N & (N - 1)), "FFT length has to be a power of two");

    if (N == 1)
        return data;

    auto even = ifft(data[std::slice(0, N / 2, 2)]);
    auto odd = ifft(data[std::slice(1, N / 2, 2)]);

    auto result = std::valarray<std::complex<T>>(N);
    for (size_t k = 0; k < N / 2; ++k)
    {
        auto t = std::exp(std::complex<T>(0, 2 * std::numbers::pi * T(k) / N));
        result[k] = (even[k] + odd[k] * t) / T(sqrt(N));
        result[k + N / 2] = (even[k] - odd[k] * t) / T(sqrt(N));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: The scaling coefficient is part of the FFT definition that isn't standardized.  Both (1, 1/N) and (1/sqrt(N), 1/sqrt(N)) are very common choices.  Your "fix" however, is completely wrong, because it compounds the scaling factor at every recursion level except the last, where you have `return data` with no scaling.

Comment: A better fix would be for `ifft` to recurse to `fft` (which has no scaling factor applied), so that only the outermost recursion level of `ifft` applies scaling (which shall be `1/N` scaling).

Comment: @BenVoigt But I can't just replace the recursive calls to `ifft(...)` with calls to `fft(...)` right? Am I correct in the assumption that I would have to time-reverse the result of `fft(...)`?

Comment: Hmmm, my recollection that "IFFT is just FFT with a scaling factor" must be a bit rusty.  However, there are three possible corrections to make that work: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Expressing_the_inverse_DFT_in_terms_of_the_DFT

Comment: Also, time reversing the results may be as simple as exchanging `even[k] + odd[k]` with `even[k] - odd[k]` in the `ifft` for-loop (both sum and difference are already present)

Comment: @BenVoigt I am unabled to get the IFFT to work when recursing to `fft(...)`. I did however implement a version which applies the scaling coefficient after the IFFT is done, which works correctly.